# Can't see results in real time when painting on top of a material

Tags: texture-painting

I'm trying texture painting for the first time by painting on top of an existing texture (I want to add dust to parts of a car model). I'm following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eS3bp8f3i2U

**Problem:** I can't see the results of my painting in real time in the Rendered 3D viewport. Sometimes switching to the UV Editor and back to the 3D Viewport will make the latest brush strokes visible, sometimes not. The only sure way to see painting results is as follows:

I see that my brush strokes are saved to an external PNG file, but the only time that file appears to be updated is when I Ctrl+Q to quit, whereupon I'll get a dialog that says, "Save changes before closing? Save 1 modified image(s)." When I reload the Blender file my brush strokes are now visible in the 3D Viewport, but again, why aren't the results visible in real time like the video tutorial? Thanks. Blender 3.3.1, Windows 11

[blend file](http://www.arcadiastreet.com/share/texture_painting_debug.blend)

Comment: Hello, I can't download the file with the current link, could you relink?

Comment: @moonboots Did you try right-clicking on the link and selecting "Save link as..." ?

Comment: oh ok it works  ;)

Comment: You don't precise in what mode you are, I don't think that you can paint in real time in Rendered Preview mode, switch to Material Preview mode, in the N panel > Texture Slots, choose the Material mode and in the Shader Editor select the Image Texture node you want to paint on, it seems to work as it is supposed to

Comment: That works! Knowing me, I figured I was missing something basic. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't precise in what mode you are, I don't think that you can paint in real time in *Rendered Preview* mode, and in *Solid* mode you'll only see one of your image textures, so switch to *Material Preview* mode, in the *N panel > Texture Slots*, choose the *Material* mode and in the *Shader Editor* select the *Image Texture* node you want to paint on, it seems to work as it is supposed to.